# How to integrate Prometheus with Kubernetes where both are running on different host?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

My prometheus server is running on different server. Also I have another kubernetes cluster. So, I need monitoring kubernetes pod metrics using prometheus running on different servers.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Please mentione that.

Answer (score 0):

To monitor external cluster I would take advantage of [Prometheus federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/#use-cases) topology.

- In your Kubernetes cluster install [node-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) pods and configure Prometheus with short-term storage.
- Expose the Prometheus service (you can follow this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/)) outside of Kubernetes cluster, this can be done either by LB or a node port.
- Configure the Prometheus server to scrape metrics from Kubernetes endpoints configuring them with correct tags and proper authentication.